# Session not working in Laravel 5.7 after successful Login Authentication and Redirection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

[image]Session is not working after successful Login Authentication and Redirection to this accounts.blade page in Laravel 5.7.

**Account.blade**

```
$id = session('nameOfSessionKey');
if (Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY')) {
    echo 'do something with session key';
} else {
    echo 'session key dosent exist'; //this has been printed after successful redirection on login with custom "admin" guard.
}
echo "$id"; //no echo
```

**Login Controller**

---

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/account';  //redirection output
```

**Login Function**

```
$details = $request->only('email', 'password');
if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt($details)) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: can you show the output of your session ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you trying to get the user id manually from the session?

Comment: I'll update it. @Qonvex620. Please wait for a while.

Comment: To get the admin profile. @Jerodev

Comment: Then why not use the existing `auth()->id()` method?

Comment: Yes, Sir. I tried to get the ID. But it should be from Session, which is not available. and also there's a custom guard admin.

Comment: @Qonvex620, I have updated the code. I hope this helps you to help me. Thank you.